# WordPress の mw wpform プラグインで日付とタイトルをまとめて返したい

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPoressのプラグイン、MW WPFORMのために、function.phpを編集しています。

タイトルと日付をそれぞれ個別にはフォームへ返せるようになったのですが、これらをまとめて返したいです。

うまく説明ができず申し訳ないのですが、下記のコードだと日付だけが返ってきます。そして日付とタイトルをreturn〇〇〇から順番を入れかえると、今度はタイトルだけが返ってきます。

日付とタイトルを一緒に返すことはできるのでしょうか。

```php
function my_mwform_value( $value, $name ) {
    if ( $name === 'kijidate' && !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) && !is_array( $_GET['post_id'] ) ) {
        return get_the_date( 'Y年m月d日', $_GET['post_id'] );
        return get_the_title($_GET['post_id']);
    }
    return $value;   
}
add_filter( 'mwform_value_mw-wp-form-14378', 'my_mwform_value', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

returnを連続するのは不可能です。

```
return get_the_date( 'Y年m月d日', $_GET['post_id'] ).get_the_title($_GET['post_id']);
```

Comment: やりたかったことができました！本当にありがとうございます！